# How to change css of previous siblings

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to change previous elements when one is hovered on, so when a div with class item is hovered the rest of the divs with item change to smaller size except that one. Could somebody help me figure out how to select all of the previous elements with jquery.

This is the jquery I'm trying to use-

```
$("div.item").hover.prevAll().css('opacity', '.4')
$("div.item").hover.prevAll().css('width', '10%')
```

Html

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="item">
    <img width="100%" height="100px;" style="background:#000; float: left;"/>
    <div class="child">
      info
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Rest of the divs, or the previous ones?  Previous ones use `prevAll()`, rest of the divs use `siblings()`. In any regard, you should try to keep the CSS rules out of your JavaScript and reference a CSS class when possible.

**CSS**:

```
.item.hovered {
    opacity : .4;
    width   : 10%;
}
```

**jQuery**:

```
$('div.item').hover(function() {
    $(this).prevAll().toggleClass('hovered');
});
```

Demo with previous divs: http://jsfiddle.net/Q89R7/

Demo with all siblings: http://jsfiddle.net/2F3Ae/

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
$("div.item").hover(function(){
   $(this).prevAll().css({'opacity': '4','width':'10%'})
});
```

Or you can try individual properties like

```
$(this).prevAll().css('opacity','4');
$(this).prevAll().css('width','10%');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
$("div.item").hover(function(){
    $(this).siblings().css({
        opacity: '.4',
        width: '10%'
    });
}, function(){
    $(this).siblings().css({
        opacity: 1,
        width: ''
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/A4bKX/)

Comment: @rjf0909 what is the problem

Comment: I don't know, none of these seem to but they do on jsfiddle so I am trying to determine if it's my css

Answer (score 1):

to change for rest of the divs you need to use `siblings()` , `prevAll()` gets all the elements which is present before that element.
try this.

```
 $("div.item").hover(function(){
   $(this).siblings().css({'opacity': '.4',width:'10%'})
}, function(){
   $(this).siblings().css({opacity: 1,width: ''});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eYMHq/1/)**

Jquery

```
  $("div.item").hover(function () {     
      $("div.item").css('opacity', '.4');
      $("div.item").css('width', '10%');
      $(this).css('opacity', '1');
      $(this).css('width', '10%');
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use any javascript, you can do this with just CSS.

```
#parent:hover div.item { opacity:0.4;width:10%;}
#parent div.item:hover { opacity:1;width:100%;}
```

Comment: +1 This is sexy. I would choose this over my answer unless you intend to animate the transformations.